# Does ECS service with "awslogs" driver use NAT for pushing logs to cloudwatch?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, amazon-vpc, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I have an ECS service with awslogs turned on. While its working fine, I wanted to understand if the logs are transmitted via NAT/ internet-gw or local network.
What is the best way to validate it as well ? I would want logs not to be flowing through internet to save some money on data transfer.

My VPC routing configurations looks as like below
[image]

and routes configured as below

[image]

FYI: the ecs task is running in private subnet.

Comment: And you have NAT Gateway or NAT Instance as well to connect your private subnet with internet. Right?

Comment: for now, i only have NAT gateway. Based on our usage and cost/maintenance implications we may move to NAT instance

Answer (score 2):

As per [why are my Amazon ECS container logs not delivered to Amazon CloudWatch Logs](https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/ecs-container-logs-cloudwatch) post on **AWS Knowledge Center**, you should create an interface Amazon VPC endpoint for CloudWatch Logs.

> If your Amazon Virtual Private Cloud (Amazon VPC) doesn't have an internet gateway, and your tasks use the awslogs log driver to send log information to CloudWatch Logs, then be sure that you created an interface Amazon VPC endpoint for CloudWatch Logs. For more information, see Using CloudWatch Logs with interface VPC endpoints.

Now, if you have both **Internet Gateway/NAT Gateway/NAT Instance** and **VPC Endpoint**, then VPC Endpoint takes the priority as per this link [vantage.sh](https://www.vantage.sh/blog/nat-gateway-vpc-endpoint-savings#:%7E:text=It%20is%20possible%20to%20use,a%20more%20specific%20address%20range.).

> It is possible to use a NAT Gateway and a VPC Endpoint in the same subnet. The VPC endpoint traffic will take priority since it is a more specific address range.

Docs [says](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/privatelink/gateway-endpoints.html):

> If there is a route that sends all internet traffic (0.0.0.0/0) to an internet gateway, the endpoint route takes precedence.

Comment: Thank you! this helps. I used aws network reachability analyser to validate the data flow. Is there any better mechanism ?

Comment: You can check VPC flow logs as well.